# ESLINT:Unexpected use of file extension "css" for "!css-variables-loader!variables.css"

Tags: javascript

I want to import a css modules,It needs to be compiled with  "css-variables-loader"

```
import variables from '!css-variables-loader!variables.css'
```

But reported a mistake:

ESLINT: Unexpected use of file extension "css" for "!css-variables-loader!variables.css"

How to solve it?